# Speed up bind queries by forcing cache

Tags: debian, dns, cache, bind, dig

I have a BIND server on Debian and would like to know what are the options that could allow me to cache domain requests so that served queries are stored in RAM for a while without having to interrogate external servers for data.

My setup is a forwarder only BIND. All the guides I'm looking around talk about cache but there's not an explicit option, just tutorials in how use bind.

Do the caching part in BIND is done in an implicit way or can I tweak it somehow?

I do have an RPZ zone for blocking, that one is fast, but by my tests the forwarded domains are not cached, judging by the speed of the queries.

Answer (score 1):

Caching is automatic and always-on in BIND, like it is in probably every DNS resolver out there. However, it honors the TTL indicated in the response – if a record has a TTL of 60 seconds then it'll be cached for only 60 seconds, although an hour to a day is more common.

(And because you're querying another cache, then the TTL of the reply *your* resolver receives will already be reduced by the amount of time that the record spent in your *upstream* cache, so it can be much lower than original; e.g. if your upstream already had the 60sec reply cached for 15 seconds, then your BIND will receive it with a 45sec TTL! So using a forwarder may actually be counter-productive.)

If you test with `dig`, TTL is the number in the 2nd field of each answer record (measured in seconds). With nslookup on Windows, try the `-d` option.

Some other resolvers have options to [enforce a minimum TTL](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/287908/2168). According to that page, BIND doesn't; but if I remember correctly, recent versions do have a `serve-stale` option which works somewhat differently but should achieve the same effect.

Comment: Ok, but searching around I found that is possible maybe define a ttl value inside the forwarders in the named.conf.options the syntax should be something like forwarders { 8.8.8.8 ttl 3600 } is this right?